# Gauss-Seidel method and coupled gradient methods for matrix

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

I have a matrix

[image]

and I should write code using Gauss-Seidel and coupled gradient methods taking  the structure of the matrix.

`Ax = e` where `A` is matrix and `e` is vector with values of 1

I don't know how to write code using coupled gradient methods and my Gauss-Seidel algorithm don't have main part where I add this all thinks

```
//part of gauss-seidel method    

const int N = 128;             //size of array
const int no_of_iter = 128;    //iterations

int main() {
  double result[N];            //array for result
  double result_pom[N];        //temporary result array
  double sum = 0.0;

  int x, y;                            
  for (int i = 0; i < no_of_iter; i++) {
    for (y = 0; y < N; y++) {
       result_pom[y] = result[y]; //set values of result to result_pom
    }

    for (x = 0; x < N; x++) {
      sum = 0.0;
      //for functions where I add (x,y) el

      result[x] = 0.25 * (1 - sum); //because 4 is dominant el of matrix and
                                    //1 is value of vector e
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Provide a [mcve] if you have trouble implementing GS.

Comment: I have a problem how to  correctly iterate throughout the matrix and summarize all elements in gauss-seidel method - main function reprezent gauss-seidel method without main structure with summarize all elements